# Seleccionar todos los input menos uno

Tags: javascript

Ahora mismo intento seleccionar todos los input que contiene el documento menos uno, que está en `hidden`, y no quiero que se vea en ningún sitio (PD: Es el último input seleccionado siempre).

Tengo este código:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

Y el input que necesito eliminar de la selección se forma dinámicamente así:

```
for (let i in params){
         var hi0     =   document.createElement('input');
         hi0.type    =   'hidden'; //cambiar a text si hay que verlo
         hi0.name    =   i;
         hi0.value   =   params[i];
         this.div0.querySelector('form').appendChild(hi0);
      }
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para eliminar ese input de la selección?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el selector :not para excluir los que no te interesan y a este le puedes añadir una regla de tipo ; 'input:not([type="hidden"])'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Seleccionar todos los input menos uno</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form></form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
    var Hiddenparams=["Param1","Param2","Param3","Param4"];    
    var NotHidden=["N1","N2","N3","N4"];
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        for (let i in Hiddenparams){
            var hi0     =   document.createElement('input');
            hi0.type    =   'hidden'; //cambiar a text si hay que verlo
            hi0.name    =   i;
            hi0.value   =   Hiddenparams[i];
            document.querySelector('form').appendChild(hi0);
        }
        for (let i in NotHidden){
            var hi0     =   document.createElement('input');
            hi0.type    =   'text'; //cambiar a text si hay que verlo
            hi0.name    =   i;
            hi0.value   =   NotHidden[i];
            document.querySelector('form').appendChild(hi0);
        }

        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="hidden"])');
        console.log("Inputs: ",inputs);

    });
    
</script>
```

Comment: Que bueno, ni lo conocía ni me sonaba. Muchisimas gracias